# package.json file path dependency has all files

Tags: javascript, npm

I created a JavaScript package and this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "types": "dist/src/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.12.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.12.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

When I run `npm pack`, I get a `tar.gz` file with only this inside of it:

```
dist  package.json  readme.md
```

I have another JavaScript project which uses this package (via a file dependency), here's the `package.json` for that one:

```
"mylib": "file:../../mylib",
```

However, after running `npm install`, when I run `ls node_modules/mylib` I see this:

```
dist  node_modules  package  scripts  src  custom.d.ts  package.json  package-lock.json  postcss.config.js  readme.md   tsconfig.json  tsconfig.webpack.json  webpack.config.js
```

Basically, using a file path dependency brings in all the files of the library, but I want it to bring only the files that the library lists in its `files` key in the `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when using the `file:` syntax for declaring filesystem-based NPM dependencies, NPM will symlink the entire directory as the dependency, meaning that it doesn't respect the `"files"` property which you have declared.

One way to get around this is to point your filesystem dependency to the `dist/` directory of your package like so:

```
"common-dependency": "file:../common/dist/src",
```